# Ordering hierarchical data in a pivot-like way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a hierarchical dataset which needs to be presented in a certain way. Items of the same hierarchy paths needs to be presented in successive order. Further parents should be listed above their children.
Appreciate any guidance to achieve the same..

Thank You

** sample dataset **

```
level   Parent  Child
0   z   z
1   z   o
1   z   p
2   p   t
2   p   q
2   o   r
```

** what i tried **

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')
df1=df.pivot(columns='level',values='Child')
df1.fillna('-',inplace=True)
df1
```

** my result **

```
level   0   1   2
0   z   -   -
1   -   o   -
2   -   p   -
3   -   -   t
4   -   -   q
5   -   -   r
```

** desired result **

```
level   0   1   2
0   z   -   -
1   -   o   -
2   -   -   r
3   -   p   -
4   -   -   t
5   -   -   q
```

Comment: In your desired result, can you add an explanation of the meaning of the index column. i.e. why is `r` on the same row as `o` but `t` and `q` aren't on the same row as `p`?

Comment: Thanks Dan! copy paste issue from my side - Here is an updated desired result.

level   0   1   2
0   z   -   -
1   -   o   -
2   -   -   r
3   -   p   -
4   -   -   t
5   -   -   q

Comment: Please post this update by **editing your question**. As you can see, it is very difficult to read it in the comments.

Comment: So it is just a case of changing the order of the rows?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it has to be in that order. Apologies for the bad format - in future,i will ensure that its properly formatted.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the future, just edit your question now and fix it.

Comment: In addition to what @Dan says, Also please provide a rationale explaining why the rows should be ordered like you show

Comment: In the input, you only have levels 0, 1, 2. Where did level 4 in the output come from?

Comment: I think, the community needs more explanation what the result should be and why to come up with any solution. If a solution is still needed, as the question is already a quite old.

Answer (score 0):

As the title states that the question is about hierarchies, the solution is should be found in some network packages like [networkx](https://networkx.org/) or [igraph](https://igraph.org/). I am not an expert in that tools, so I give an abstract solution to this question.

The writer of the question is asking for an order based on the way to the given item, e.g. going from a parent downwards the stream to the children. So the following workflow is appropriate.

1. find for each item the path from the top level to this item. (example: the last item in the list z -> p -> q)
2. Order the paths (key from top level to low level)
3. Apply the order onto the pivoted table